# Restore wired network connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

Hi My problem is the following: I was at my friend, were they had mac filter on the network. I used to clone the MAC in the network manager, but I accidentally copied it in  the wrong field, and somehow 'switched' the Device static MAC It did not dropped any error and I applied it. Now I can't get into the options, because it drops an error:

```
error editing connection: did not find a connection with UUID '(null)'
```

And the laptop cannot connect to the internet at wire, only at wifi.

Maybe is there a way that I can restore it in a file? I haven't found it in `/etc/network`, but I guess it is there somewhere.

Or is it possible, that if i reinstall the network manager with a purge it will restore everything?

I use ubuntu 14.04 with gnome3 on a thinkpad t510.

Comment: Have a look at the content of `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`. There should be a file for each network connection. Please identify the configuration file for your wired connection and [edit] your question to include its content.

Comment: That was exacly the file i was looking for :) Thank you (idk why i was thying to find it in the network folder when it was a Manager mistake) i will remove the question

Comment: If you struggle further, [edit] your question with an update and new findings. If you manage to [solve the issue yourself](/help/self-answer), please [write an answer](/help/how-to-answer) and accept it. Shoot me a message and I'll vote it up, if it's any good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the config in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` edited it with GEdit and restored the broken line

```
[802-3-ethernet]
duplex=full
mac-address=F0:DE:F1:XX:XX:XX

[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=5872a1e2-fe69-4158-aa49-844d309f91a8
type=802-3-ethernet
timestamp=1424948640

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

I restored the MAC address line to my original MAC (masked in the above listing) and it's working now.

Comment: You shouldn't publish your MAC address, because it can be used to cause mischief.

Answer (score 0):

My sulotion is:
Search: Enter "Network connection" -> Add > Ethernet -> set Automantic(DHCP) at Ipv4 and tick "require ipv4 addressing for..." -> Save.
I hope it help you!