# Error editing connection Unable to find a connection with UUID ('null')

Tags: ethernet

When I open System Settings > Network > Wired and click options, it responds with the 'Error' How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590196/restore-wired-network-connection

Answer (score 1):

Search Ubuntu: Enter "Network connection" -> Add > Ethernet -> set Automantic(DHCP) at Ipv4 and tick "require ipv4 addressing for..." -> Save.

Comment: Nothing happens after I click save.

Comment: It still says "unmanaged."

Answer (score 0):

It seems like MAC address of interface is not configured or changed:
open `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0` (if your interface eth1 then open that)
and verify MAC address is correctly added or if not added then add like :

```
mac-address=DC:A9:71:59:9F:AC
```

your correct MAC address solve your problem. if not then you can generate UUID for interface.

```
uuidgen eth0
ffc3c3a4-6c82-457b-8f58-7d99db1813c1
```

and add manually `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0`

```
uuid=ffc3c3a4-6c82-457b-8f58-7d99db1813c1
```